# Does a ZeroMQ Router and Dealer have to be in the same (Python) process for two way communication to be achieved?

Tags: python, zeromq, router

Here is a simple req-rep service. Usually zmq.REP and zmq.REQ would suffice, but this is not the case application that I am building. Below is a script that performs a client server communication. The server runs in a thread. The communication works as expected. The client sends a message, the server receives the message and then sends a message to the client, which receives the message.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import zmq

def worker_thread():
    cxt = zmq.Context.instance()
    worker = cxt.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    worker.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, 'A')
    worker.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559")

    for _ in range(10):
        request = worker.recv()
        print 'worker recieved'
        worker.send_multipart(['A', "data_recieved"])

cxt = zmq.Context.instance()
client = cxt.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
client.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5559')

Thread(target=worker_thread).start()
time.sleep(2)

for _ in range(10):
    client.send_multipart(['A', 'data'])
    request = client.recv()
    print 'worker responded'
```

When this code is separated into two scripts, a client and server, the communication fails. The client sends a message, but the server never receives it. The code is as follows:

client:

```
import time
import zmq

cxt = zmq.Context.instance()
client = cxt.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
client.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5559')

for _ in range(10):
    client.send_multipart(['A', 'data'])
    request = client.recv()
    print 'worker responded'
```

server:

```
import time
import zmq

cxt = zmq.Context.instance()
worker = cxt.socket(zmq.DEALER)
worker.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, 'A')
worker.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559")

for _ in range(10):
    request = worker.recv()
    print 'worker recieved'
    worker.send_multipart(['A', "data_recieved"])
```

The only reason I can think of that could be causing the failure in communication is that the zmq.ROUTER and zmq.DEALER are running in separate scripts, and thus separate processes.

Comment: Nope, they can be in separate processes, separate executables, on separate computers or on separate networks.  Some other problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you just mistakenly reversed the two socket types.

Router socket behaves like a Rep socket and Dealer behaves like a Req. See for details: http://zeromq.org/tutorials:dealer-and-router.

Router and Dealer are special in the sense that they allow async messaging where Req/Rep are specifically made for sync exchanges. I don't know why your first script works but you should probably try to reverse sockets.

Here is an example in C# that mimics yours in python. These are two separate processes.

Process A:

```
const string Endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5559";

void Main()
{
    using (var ctx = NetMQContext.Create())
    using (var worker = ctx.CreateRouterSocket())
    {
        worker.Connect(Endpoint);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            NetMQMessage message = router.ReceiveMessage();
            Console.WriteLine("#{0}: worker received: {1}", i, string.Join(", ", message.Select(t => t.ConvertToString())));
            message.Clear();
            message.Append("A");
            message.Append("data_recieved");
            worker.SendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Process B:

```
const string Endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5559";

void Main()
{
    using (var ctx = NetMQContext.Create())
    using (var client = ctx.CreateDealerSocket())
    {
        client.Options.Identity = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A");
        client.Bind(Endpoint);

        var message = new NetMQMessage();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            message.Clear();
            message.Append("A");
            message.Append("data");
            client.SendMessage(message);
            var response = client.ReceiveMessage();
            Console.WriteLine("#{0}: worker responded", i);
        }
    }
}
```

The output seems to be what you're expecting :

Process A:

```
#0: worker received: A, A, data
#1: worker received: A, A, data
#2: worker received: A, A, data
#3: worker received: A, A, data
#4: worker received: A, A, data
#5: worker received: A, A, data
#6: worker received: A, A, data
#7: worker received: A, A, data
#8: worker received: A, A, data
#9: worker received: A, A, data
```

Process B:

```
#0: worker responded
#1: worker responded
#2: worker responded
#3: worker responded
#4: worker responded
#5: worker responded
#6: worker responded
#7: worker responded
#8: worker responded
#9: worker responded
```

Cheers